# My function returns an object. How to set return value to specific key value in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await

I have a function in my react code as so...

```
  const getLatLngFromAddress = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await Geocode.fromAddress(state.address.address1)
      const { lat, lng } = response.results[0].geometry.location;
      return { lat, lng }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err.message)
    }
  }
```

returns an object. I would like to set my state to only a specific key of the object and not the object itself...

```
  useEffect(async () => {
    setState({
      ...state,
      address: {
        ...state.address,
        lat: await getLatLngFromAddress().lat,
        lng: await getLatLngFromAddress().lng
      }
    })

  }, []);
```

useEffect above returns undefined. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to read the properties from the **value resolved from the promise**. Currently you are trying to read them from the promise itself and then `await`ing those `undefined` values.

```
lat: (await getLatLngFromAddress()).lat,
```

However, you are calling `getLatLngFromAddress` twice. Store the values in variables and then reuse them instead.

```
  useEffect(async () => {
    const latlng = await getLatLngFromAddress()
    setState({
      ...state,
      address: {
        ...state.address,
        ...latlng,
      }
    })

  }, []);
```

Answer (score 3):

Call the method once, and set it to your state:

```
useEffect(async () => {
    const {lat, lng} = await getLatLngFromAddress();
    setState({
      ...state,
      address: {
        ...state.address,
        lat: lat,
        lng: lng
      }
    })

  }, []);
```

You can also spread the result if you dont want to repeat all variables:

```
useEffect(async () => {
    const result = await getLatLngFromAddress();
    setState({
      ...state,
      address: {
        ...state.address,
        ...result
      }
    })

  }, []);
```